# What is the best alternative to Prism Event Aggregator for Net6

Tags: .net-core, event-handling, prism

A couple of years back I wrote a WPF application and used Prism Event aggregation for notifying my submodules (both visual and non visual) for changes. It worked fine and I kind of liked it.

Now I'm about to write a Net 6 (Core) application and I was wondering what you guys suggest that I use for event aggregation in my application.
(If I'm not mistaken Prism Event Aggregator is for .Net 4.x)

King regards
Magnus

Answer (score 2):

You can use Prism's event aggregator independent from the wpf- or xamarin.forms- or whatever features. I've included it in a xamarin-native app where it's literally the only class from Prism used.

Nothing wrong with just including the [Prism.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Core/#supportedframeworks-body-tab) nuget and using the event aggregator.

Just make sure to register it as a singleton from the main thread, if you want to use `ThreadOption.UIThread`.

Comment: Thanks @Haukinger for that information. For some strange reason (my brain not working correctly?) I was under the impression that Prism Eventaggregator was tightly coupled with the .Net Framework (i.e 4.x)